# Error by creating a list of QGraphicsItems

Tags: qt4, qlist, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsScene on which I would like to draw some special curves. For that I made a class in which I define these special curves as a new QGraphicsItem:

```
    #include < QGraphicsItem>

    class Clothoid : public QGraphicsItem
    {
    public:
        Clothoid(QPoint startPoint, QPoint endPoint);
        virtual ~Clothoid();

        QPoint sPoint;
        QPoint ePoint;
        float startCurvature;
        float endCurvature;
        float clothoidLength;

    protected:
        QRectF boundingRect() const;
        void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);

    };
```

and I try to insert each item twice: once in an array I defined:

```
    QList< Clothoid> clothoids;
```

and once in the scene:

```
    void renderArea::updateClothoid(const QPoint &p1, const QPoint &p2)
    {
        Clothoid *temp = new Clothoid(p1, p2);

        clothoids.append(&temp);

        scene->addItem(&temp);
    }
```

But I get these 2 errors:

no matching function for call to 'QList::append(Clothoid**)'

and

no matching function for call to 'QGraphicsScene::addItem(Clothoid**)'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be:

```
clothoids.append(temp);
scene->addItem(temp);
```

The QList should be defined as:

```
QList<Clothoid*> clothoids;
```

Comment: tried like that and now the error for the qgraphicsscene disappeared but the one for the qlist is still there.

Comment: The QList should contains pointers to Clothoid objects. I have updated my answer with the code.